# Using apex:panelGrid Inside of a div tag Causes Text To Be Displayed Outside of Div

Tags: jquery, html, css, visualforce, apex

I'm trying to implement the drag and drop demonstrated in the last half of this [Developing Applications with jQuery video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6je8AV6NuPM) from a Salesforce presentation around Dec 2010.

I've got it working but I had a problem putting an apex:panelGrid inside of a div tag.

When I used the apex:panelGrid inside of the div tag, I actually got a box that was separate from the embedded text. The box behaved the way I wanted it to, but the text from the apex:outputLabel and apex:outputField was outside the box and did not drag and drop. It worked in the above video, but not on my page.

When I replace the entire apex:panelGrid with an HTML table, then the whole thing behaves exactly as I want it to and as in the video.

I am assuming that something has changed over the years since the video was made, but I can't figure out what or why.

Any ideas?

Here is the entire apex:PageBlock section of the code. Currently, the HTML table is commented out, but you can see the two different attempts.

```
<apex:PageBlock title="Installed Widgets" mode="edit" id="installBlock">
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="section">
        <apex:repeat value="{!installedWidgets}" var="w">
            <!-- <div class="widget" data-id="{!w.Id}" style="{!IF(w.Status__c == 'Maintenance Required','border-radius: 10px','border-radius: 5px')}">-->
            <div class="widget" data-id="{!w.Id}">
                <!-- This does not work and places a box that is separate from the embedded text. The box has the behavior I want, but the text is outside the box.-->
                <!--<apex:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label,value">
                    <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Widget__c.fields.Name.label}"/>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!w.Name}"/>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Widget__c.fields.Status__c.label}"/>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!w.Status__c}"/>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Widget__c.fields.Serial_Number__c.label}"/>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!w.Serial_Number__c}"/>
                </apex:panelGrid>-->
                <!-- This HTML table does what I want it to. -->
                <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label">{!$ObjectType.Widget__c.fields.Name.label}</td>
                    <td class="value">{!w.Name}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label">{!$ObjectType.Widget__c.fields.Status__c.label}</td>
                    <td class="value">{!w.Status__c}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label">{!$ObjectType.Widget__c.fields.Serial_Number__c.label}</td>
                    <td class="value">{!w.Serial_Number__c}</td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:PageBlock>
```

Comment: I found part of the problem. Looking at the source code in the browser, it's generating unclosed div tags as follows.

    <tr>
      <td class="data2Col  first " colSpan="2">
        <div class="widget" data-id="a095000000DPP4rAAH">
      </td>
    </tr>

And then closing them later in the code

    <tr>
      <td class="data2Col " colSpan="2">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

Now I just have to figure out if this is a bug or if I am using bad Apex coding practice.

Comment: You should probably drop the html tag in favor of a Salesforce tag.  Non-Salesforce developers aren't likely to have an answer and Salesforce devs are less likely to find it without the tag.